# How to find weighted covariance matrix of Excel rows?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, covariance

I am very new to python, in fact this is my first code in python.
I am attempting to find the covariance matrix for 4 rows of data with each element having a decreasing weight date-wise

I need to calculate the 4 by 4 covariance matrix 
I have to use python where i have calculated the returns and the weights
to find the covariance matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
xl = pd.ExcelFile('path+file.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet 1')
df['spxr']=np.log(df.SPX/df.SPX.shift(-1))
df['djir']=np.log(df.DJI/df.DJI.shift(-1))
df['vixr']=np.log(df.VIX/df.VIX.shift(-1))
df['vxdr']=np.log(df.VXD/df.VXD.shift(-1))
df['weights']=(0.06)*(0.94**(df.Obs-1))
df=df.fillna(0)
```

I am not sure how to use `np.cov` either

Answer (score 1):

numpy cov takes an array as an an input and outputs an array. It should be as simple as this:

```
import numpy as np

SPX = [0.000174, 0.000170, -0.000985, -0.000906]
DJI = [0.000170, 0.000175, -0.000944, -0.000887]
VIX = [-0.000985, -0.000944, 0.006568, 0.005917]
VXD = [-0.000906, -0.000887, 0.005917, 0.005573]

arr = np.array([SPX,DJI,VIX,VXD])
np.cov(arr)

>>>array([[  4.17311583e-07,   4.06027167e-07,  -2.69320633e-06,
     -2.47850075e-06],
   [  4.06027167e-07,   3.95127000e-07,  -2.61988900e-06,
     -2.41190283e-06],
   [ -2.69320633e-06,  -2.61988900e-06,   1.73845300e-05,
      1.59925507e-05],
   [ -2.47850075e-06,  -2.41190283e-06,   1.59925507e-05,
      1.47229569e-05]])
```

Or, with a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['SPX','DJI','VIX','VXD'])
np.cov(df)

>>>array([[  4.17311583e-07,   4.06027167e-07,  -2.69320633e-06,
    -2.47850075e-06],
   [  4.06027167e-07,   3.95127000e-07,  -2.61988900e-06,
    -2.41190283e-06],
   [ -2.69320633e-06,  -2.61988900e-06,   1.73845300e-05,
     1.59925507e-05],
   [ -2.47850075e-06,  -2.41190283e-06,   1.59925507e-05,
     1.47229569e-05]])
```

You might have irrelevant columns in your dataframe, in which case you can slice it like:

```
df_relevant = df.iloc[:,['spxr','djir','vixr','vxdr']]
```

Comment: Hi how do i use the weights here though? The calculation on excel is of the formula sumproduct(SPX(all rows)*SPX(all rows)*weights(all rows))

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448579/weighted-covariance-matrix-in-numpy